# Android extending Adapter vs extending BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter, baseadapter

I'm creating a custom ListView that will that will accommodate rows having different layouts (i.e. Headings, and clickable items). Is there any particular difference between my custom adapter class extending Adapter over BaseAdapter? It looks like I need to override the same methods (getItem, getView... ect) in either case. Are there any performance differences? or does one do some of the implementation for you if you call super.method()? I understand that BaseAdapter is a subclass of Adapter, but what extra functionality do you get out of it?

Cheers,
Luke.

Comment: Thanks AC, yeah sorry wrote them the wrong way around :)

Comment: It's alright, Commons clarified it anyways :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It looks like I need to override the same methods (getItem, getView... ect) in either case

You have to implement fewer methods if you inherit from `BaseAdapter` rather than creating a full implementation of the `Adapter` interface. For example, `BaseAdapter` handles `registerDataSetObserver()` and `unregisterDataSetObserver()` for you.

> Are there any performance differences?

Not usually.

> I understand that Adapter is a subclass of BaseAdapter

Absolutely not. `Adapter` is an interface, not a class. `BaseAdapter` implements `Adapter`.

> but what extra functionality do you get out of it?

You do not get any "extra functionality" out of `Adapter`, because `Adapter` is an interface.